# how to connect odac client 11g with asp.net gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g client and want to connect with asp.net?

How i can populate gridview with oracle 11g?

Is there any good piece of code working there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have in details: [How to connect ASP.NET GridView to Oracle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2006/03/17/connecting-asp-net-2-0-gridview-to-oracle.aspx)